# Strange behaviour while sorting CMFCListCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc

I have extended `CMFCListCtrl` class mainly to be able to easily sort by columns. From what I learned, it should be enough to implement `Sort` and `OnCompareItems` functions.

What happens is that sort works fine with 1st column which type is `integer` but it gives strange ordering for 2nd column, which type is `string`. There are no errors, ordering is changed but not alphabetically.

```
int MyCMFCListCtrl::OnCompareItems(LPARAM lParam1, LPARAM lParam2, int iColumn)
{
    if (iColumn == 0)
    {
        if (lParam1 > lParam2)
            return -1;
        else if (lParam1 < lParam2)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    else if (iColumn == 1)
    {
        CString strCol1, strCol2;
        strCol1 = GetItemText(lParam1, iColumn);
        strCol2 = GetItemText(lParam2, iColumn);
        return strCol1.Compare(strCol2);
    }
    return 0;
}

void MyCMFCListCtrl::Sort(int iColumn, BOOL bAscending, BOOL bAdd)
{
    // Sort available for first and second column
    if (iColumn > 1) return;
    CMFCListCtrl::Sort(iColumn, bAscending, bAdd);
}
```

Values I get in `OnCompareItems` are ok for both columns. But the end result is valid only for the first one. Are there any other functions necessary for this to work?

Comment: _"but it gives invalid ordering"_: what does that mean? Is there an error message some where? Does the program crash? Is it an ASSERT? Please [edit] your question and be more specific.

Comment: Also check if `strCol1` and `strCol2` _actually_ contain the right strings. Put  `TRACE("OnCompareItems: %s %s\n", strCol1, strCol2);` right before `return strCol1.Compare(strCol2);` and check the debug output.

Comment: *Are there any other functions necessary for this to work?* -- We have no idea what your actual data is.  So right now we cannot assume the sort is "not working".

Comment: Also what does this mean: _"which type is test."_?

Comment: Is it possible to simply use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfclistctrl-class?view=vs-2019#setsortcolumn (`SetSortColumn`) function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncorrect sorting of columns ClistCtrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229216/uncorrect-sorting-of-columns-clistctrl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CMFCListCtrl::Sort` will call `CListCtrl::SortItems`. `SortItems` will pass `LPARAM` item data to the callback function. This `LPARAM` is a value which can be set with `SetItemData`.

That means the `lParam1` and `lParam2` in `OnCompareItems`, refere to `LPARAM` data only.

`GetItemText(lParam1, iColumn)` is undefined behavior in this case because `lParam1` does not refer to row number.

See also documentation for [`LVM_SORTITEMS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-sortitems) and [`LVM_SORTITEMSEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-sortitemsex)

---

You can override `Sort` and call `SortItemsEx` instead. This way `lParam1` and `lParam2` will refer to row numbers, and `GetItemText(lParam1, iColumn)` will be a valid call, as shown below. Note that `(iColumn == 0)` condition is used only if `SetItemData` was called earlier.

```
int MyCMFCListCtrl::OnCompareItems(LPARAM lParam1, LPARAM lParam2, int iColumn)
{
    if(iColumn == 0)//assuming SetItemData was called earlier
        return lParam1 - lParam2;

    CString strCol1 = GetItemText(lParam1, iColumn);
    CString strCol2 = GetItemText(lParam2, iColumn);
    return strCol1.Compare(strCol2);
}

void MyCMFCListCtrl::Sort(int iColumn, BOOL bAscending, BOOL bAdd)
{
    if(iColumn == 0)//assuming SetItemData was called earlier
    {
        //call SortItem and get LPARAM data in call back function
        CMFCListCtrl::Sort(iColumn, bAscending, bAdd);
        return;
    }

    //call SortItemEx instead, get row numbers in callback function
    CWaitCursor wait;
    GetHeaderCtrl().SetSortColumn(iColumn, bAscending, bAdd);
    m_iSortedColumn = iColumn;
    m_bAscending = bAscending;
    SortItemsEx(CompareProc, (LPARAM)this);
}
```